# How to return objects from array by value of a single property

Tags: mysql

**MySql version:** 5.7.19

**Table:** users

**Field in table users:** contests

**Type field contests:** JSON

Data example in the field contests

```
[{"name": "Mihaello Julders", "text": "any text", "photo": "photo.jpg", "profileLink": "any link"}, {"name": "Алексей Якобчук", "text": "any text", "photo": "photo.jpg", "profileLink": "any link"}]
```

Problem:
I need to return one or more objects if the property name contains the specified name.

Do i understand correctly that i need to use

```
select
JSON_EXTRACT(members, "$[*].name") from `users` where JSON_EXTRACT(members, "$[*].name") = 'Mihaello Julders'
```

However this does not work, tell me what correct write this query?

Comment: Your query doesn't make any sense. You are trying to `SELECT x FROM y WHERE x = 'value'` which will simply return `value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After learning documentation i maked next query

```
select
        JSON_EXTRACT(contests, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(contests->'$[*].name', 'one', '%Mihaello%')))
    from 
        users
```

This solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

What does your `users` table look like? If you want `n` rows of `users.contests` as you mention in your question then, assuming the table has a `contests` column,

```
select
contests
from users
where JSON_EXTRACT(members, "$[*].name") = 'Mihaello Julders';
```

This will give you `n` rows of user contests where `users.members` (your json column) has the specified `name` property (Mihaello Julders).

EDIT

See the [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html) for more information. You mention the above solution returns an empty set. This is either because your users table is empty or there is a problem with the json--either you're looking for the wrong name or the name property isn't where you think it is.

This answer will return a non empty set if you have values in your `members` column like

```
[
    {" name": "Michaello Julders"}
]
```

Comment: sorry it's mine mistake

Comment: it's work if add **IS NOT NULL** but a get all names not one